# How would I use k-nearest neighbours to solve this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, k-nearest-neighbour

I am not too sure how to use K-NN to calculate the error on this data set (as shown below).

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14KT.jpg

Comment: @nsc10 Where exactly did you get stuck ? One can surely write down a complete solution, but it would be more helpful (especially for you regarding the learning experience) if you would tell use what you have already did. For example, do you already know how k-NN and leave-one-out-crossvalidation works ?

Comment: @steffen Thanks for the reply, I know how k-NN works but am not competent with leave-one-out-cross validation. I am not too sure how to start this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to do this loop:

Take one of the points and put it aside.
Train the kNN (training is just copying the points)

Now take that point and evaluate the kNN output: take a look at the k-closests points. And assign the label accordingly. If it does not match the label of the point, then it is an error, otherwise not.

Make sure you understand how kNN assigns a label to a sample.